# How to disconnect a running bash job from the shell in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script that starts a server on a remote VM. All works great until I close the shell where I executed the script. When the shell closes, so does the server.
After some looking around I found the following:

1. `&` will send the job to the background when executed with the symbol
2. `disown -h` will disconnect the job from the shell and allow it to run regardless of the shell.

The command I used is:

```
./startServer.sh nasb_wxscat160_catalog-4.1.6 1.0.8 > catalog-log.txt & disown -h
```

When I closed the shell and checked using `ps -ef | grep java` to see if the job is still working I did see it in the list. However when I tried to connect to the server it was unresponsive.

On deeper inspection, the log file was filled just until I closed the shell and using the `ps -m` flag I say the process jobs were not working.

Has any one encountered some thing of this sort?

Comment: See: http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup

Comment: @PaulR thank you. but can you explain the connection between the shell closing and the out to file?

Answer (score 2):

For one-off jobs which do not daemonize themselves, I usually run them in a screen session.  The disadvantage is that you have to start screen before starting the job.  My process is usually something like this:

```
% screen -D -R   # start a new screen session, with reattachment options
% command_to_run_job
ctrl-A ctrl-D
```

That will run the job in the foreground, then detach from the screen session.  Then you can log out, and later reconnect to it with another "screen -D -R"

Comment: thank you. i am new to all of this so can you explain what is a screen session?

Comment: screen is a virtual tty software that allows you to detach a terminal.

Comment: Natim is right.   [Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) is a window manager for terminals.  It's really useful if you're working on remote terminals.  I suggest reading the man page (with the command "man screen").

Answer (score 0):

The other thing you could do is to use `supervisord` or `circus` to run your program and make sure it will restart automatically if it stops.

http://circus.readthedocs.org